# Get Resolved Issue Field Names JIRA REST

Tags: jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I want to get the names of fields when resolving an issue. I can get the field names while creating an issue. I want the field names for resolving an issue. Any idea how should i do ?

Comment: can you explain exactly what you are trying to do? are you resolving issue using REST call by passing field values ?

Comment: I am trying to just get the field names required to resolve an issue.